# Find files with latest dates with find command

Tags: arrays, shell, scripting, find

I have a piece of code where I need to find the latest modified date file of the below mentioned 3 patterns.

```
array=( $(find /path -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name "REF_DATA*" -o -name "XR_CUST_LIST*"  -o -name "PB_INSIGHTS*" \) -printf '%f\n' ))
```

Basically there can files of many dates at /path directory, but i need to pick the latest one.
How can i achieve that?

Comment: Also asked (and answered) at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/671260/find-files-with-the-latest-date-having-multiple-pattern. Please ask on one Stack at a time. Thank you!

Comment: sure @JeffSchaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is this command line (to keep your first approach) :

```
array=( $(find /path -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name "REF_DATA*" -o -name "XR_CUST_LIST*"  -o -name "PB_INSIGHTS*" \) -printf '%c %f\n' ))|sort |tail -n 1
```

Focus on the part added/updated :

```
-printf '%c %f\n' ))|sort |tail -n 1
```

- add *%c* in printf option add the update time of the file
- add *sort* to sort this list by this date
- add *tail -n1* to have the last element of this list which is the last updated file here